# Invoke shell script in AWS Lambda using node.js

Tags: node.js, shell, amazon-web-services, lambda

I am new to AWS Lambda. I am trying to invoke a basic "Hello World" shell script from an AWS Lambda function coded in node.js.

run.js file contains the following:

---

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello, World!"
```

---

I have also coded the function by storign it in an index.js file containing the following:

---

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    exec('./run.sh' , function(error, stdout) {
        context.done(error, stdout);
    });
};
```

---

I have created a zip file containing both files and have uploaded it to AWS Lambda console by creating a new Lambda function and granting it a lambda_basic_execution role.

I was expecting to be able to see the Hello World, have tried variations of this code but so far have been unable to call a shell script from an AWS Lambda function.

Thanks in advance!

Andy

Comment: Have you read this? https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/running-executables-in-aws-lambda/

Answer (score 1):

Lambda only supports `child_process.spawn` and `child_process.spawnSync`. Try changing your call to `child_process.exec` and that should fix it for you.